# extract repeated phrase from text file Python

Tags: python, nltk

I have a huge text file of conversation (block of text), i want to extract repeated phrases (more than one word) to another text file, sorted in order of frequency

input:
[text block, single line,Word Wrapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6uu5.jpg)

output:

```
 I don't know 7345
 I want you to 5312 
 amazing experience 625
```

I'm looking for a python script

---

i have tried this script, but i could get only single word , sorted from highest to lowest occurence

```
    from IPython import get_ipython
ipy = get_ipython()
if ipy is not None:
    ipy.run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
import collections
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read input file, note the encoding is specified here 
# It may be different in your text file
file = open('test2.txt', encoding="utf8")
a= file.read()

# Stopwords
stopwords = set(line.strip() for line in open('stopwords.txt'))
stopwords = stopwords.union(set(['mr','mrs','one','two','said']))

# Instantiate a dictionary, and for every word in the file, 
# Add to the dictionary if it doesn't exist. If it does, increase the count.
wordcount = {}

# To eliminate duplicates, remember to split by punctuation, and use case demiliters.
for word in a.lower().split():
    word = word.replace(".","")
    word = word.replace(",","")
    word = word.replace(":","")
    word = word.replace("\"","")
    word = word.replace("!","")
    word = word.replace("â€œ","")
    word = word.replace("â€˜","")
    word = word.replace("*","")
    if word not in stopwords:
        if word not in wordcount:
            wordcount[word] = 1
        else:
            wordcount[word] += 1

# Print most common word
n_print = int(input("How many most common words to print: "))
print("\nOK. The {} most common words are as follows\n".format(n_print))
word_counter = collections.Counter(wordcount)
for word, count in word_counter.most_common(n_print):
    print(word, ": ", count)

# Close the file
file.close()

# Create a data frame of the most common words 
# Draw a bar chart
lst = word_counter.most_common(n_print)
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ['Word', 'Count'])
df.plot.bar(x='Word',y='Count')
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you've tried? SO is a place to help with code and issues, not to request someone does work for you..

Comment: This type of problems is generally solved by exploiting the functionalities present in regex module. Provide an example of input and desired output to get a complete answer

Comment: I propose to read about Markov chains to get an idea on how to tackle this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use nltk.ngrams from nltk package.

```
text = 'I have been I have I like this I have never been.'

ngrams = tuple(nltk.ngrams(text.split(' '), n=2))

ngrams_count = {i : ngrams.count(i) for i in ngrams}
```

Out:

```
 {('I', 'have'): 3, ('have', 'been'): 1, ('been', 'I'): 1, 
('have', 'I'): 1, ('I', 'like'): 1, ('like', 'this'): 1, 
('this', 'I'): 1, ('have', 'never'): 1, ('never', 'been.'): 1}
```

And then you can save it with pandas/txt/json etc.

You can change `n` in `nltk.ngrams` and your ngrams will be another length.

**It can be modify to this:**

```
text = 'I have been I have I like this I have never been.'
lenght = [2, 3, 4]
ngrams_count = {}
for n in lenght:
    ngrams = tuple(nltk.ngrams(text.split(' '), n=n))
    ngrams_count.update({' '.join(i) : ngrams.count(i) for i in ngrams})

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ngrams_count, ngrams_count.values())), 
                  columns=['Ngramm', 'Count']).sort_values(['Count'], 
                                                           ascending=False)
```

Out:

```
                Ngramm  Count
0               I have      3
1            have been      1
26   this I have never      1
25    like this I have      1
24       I like this I      1
23    have I like this      1
22       I have I like      1
21       been I have I      1
20    have been I have      1
19       I have been I      1
18    have never been.      1
17        I have never      1
...
```

Now we can enter n and then make a sorted dataframe. If you want, you can save it as `df.to_csv('file_name.csv')` or can take a head before that - `df.head(10)`.

For use this solution you should install nltk and pandas.

Comment: can you change the code to list only the instances where the phrase is repeated atleast twice

Comment: @SyedOmer it's easy to change. Just add `df = df[df.count > 1]`. Pandas is a very good library. As example you also can extract ngrams with count 10 as `df[df.count == 10]`.

Comment: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'

Comment: @SyedOmer I'm sorry. Change to `df = df[df.Count > 1]`. Because we have a column named `'Count'`. But `count` is function of dataframe = )

Comment: do you know how to change it to C? the script is perfect but its taking way too long.

Comment: @SyedOmer Unfortunately, I don't

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `str.count()` and count the phrase in the string

```
s = 'vash the vash the are you is he where did where did'

print('the how: {}'.format(s.count('where did')))
print('vash the: {}'.format(s.count('vash the')))
```

> ```
> the how: 2
> vash the: 2
> ```